# Adding Timestamp to Cell with existing information without deleting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am in the process of writing a Google script to enter a timestamp in addition to what is already in the cell

Example:  Current info in cell ==>  4/15/18
What I want to population ==>  4/15/18, new Date()

I'm able to populate the new date, but have not found a way to update the current date while maintaining the current cell information

Is this something that is possible?

Current Script

```
 var value = (e.value == "object" ? e.range.getValue() : e.value);
 var date = new Date ();

    if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && value == "Completed") {
    e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(date);
  }

    if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && value == "Re-assign 1") {
    e.range.offset(0, 4).setValue(date);
  }
```

Comment: I suggest clarifying your post by mentioning and [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) the environment/language/framework.

Answer (score 0):

Each Google Sheets cell is able to store a single value. Maybe creating a string that represent the old value and the new one could do what you need.

Use [getDisplayValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()) to get the value shown on the spreadsheet then concatenate it to a string representing the other value. You could try [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))